# When to use edges vs joins

Tags: arangodb

Since ArangoDB is the Multi-Model database, we have the choice of modelling connections as graph-edges or "pointers" (single or list of ID's to other documents).

In which situations would you recommend either type? What are the advantages/disadvantages (speed, query complexity/ease of use, etc) in each situation (one-one, one-many, many-many, unlimited levels), where the latter is probably the most obvious case for graph (to use traversal, shortest path, ...).

I've seen an example with authors and books, a multi-multi relationship, where edges was used. But I guess it could also have been modeled as book objects with a list of author id's? I've seen that some pro's of edges is that they can have properties, e.g. a type, but again, this can also easily be modeled as [{property:value, id:id},...]?

Comment: Here is what I am doing with my data model. I am creating all my many-many relations as edge collections, even though I do not need them for any graph queries. In future, when I need them for graph queries, I will create graphs. Until then I wont create graphs with those edges. I will use them as ordinary document collection.
Note: Edge collection is similar to ordinary Document Collection. Just that they have _from and _to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have actually written a blog post on this very matter: [Graphs in data modeling - is the emperor naked?](https://medium.com/@neunhoef/graphs-in-data-modeling-is-the-emperor-naked-2e65e2744413#.5i8necubw). This article is relatively general but addresses the whole problem with a perspective towards ArangoDB. I think my answer to your question is "It depends most on the queries that will hit your database during use." and Section "Querying graphs" in the above article explains this. Feel free to ask me directly via max (at) arangodb.com if you need more information.

Comment: So you'd say that for the bullets 1-3 (neighbor queries with/without properties/labels + fixed distance queries) joins are preferred? And use edge collections only for more "graphy" data?